# Xamarin.Forms System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, xamarin.forms

We have a Xamarin.Forms application in production. In our testing phase we didn't encounter such issues. However, in [Azure Mobile Center](https://mobile.azure.com) we are getting a number of crash issues. For example, one crash issue looks like below,

```
A task was canceled.

1 TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
2 TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
3 TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
4 TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
5 HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext ()
6 ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
...
17 RequestBuilderImplementation+<buildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>c__AnonStoreyA`1+<buildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>c__async9[T].MoveNext ()
18 ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
23 APIClient+<Portfolio>d__6.MoveNext ()
24 ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
29 PortfolioPage+<LoadPortfolio>d__3.MoveNext ()
30 ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
```

In title section it's showing, **System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException**

I have a page named **PortfolioPage** and a method named **LoadPortfolio**. Here is the method,

```
async void LoadPortfolio()
{
    try
    {
        APIResponse.Portfolio portfolio = await new APIClient().Portfolio(selectedDate);
        MessagingCenter.Send<PortfolioPage, APIResponse.Portfolio>(this, "LoadedPortfolio", portfolio);
    }
    catch (ApiException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) UIUtil.gotoAuthenticate(this);
        else
            MessagingCenter.Send<PortfolioPage, APIResponse.Portfolio>(this, "LoadedPortfolio", null);
    }
}
```

I am new to Xamarin and C#. Not sure how to extract information from this error log and how to resolve the TaskCanceledException issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen this when the request is taking too long and the mobile service times out. For instance, I most often see it if I am setting the database to rebuild from scratch for testing and try to query the database before it had finished initializing.

Answer (score 3):

The 'HttpClientHandler' functions in a similar way to Tasks from the `System.Threading.Tasks;` library. What this means is that it throws an exception when it recieves either a cancellation request, or the response is unsuccessful for some 'expected' reason.

I'd suggest wrapping the request in a try/catch block and figure out how you'd like to handle 'ThrowForNonSuccess' exceptions.

Comment: Aw heck that's frustrating. Just spent hours trying to figure out why my debounced search stopped working when in fact it was an exception in the search logic rather than the task handling. This helped me, thanks!